I am facing an issue with Google Analytics; it seems to be showing fake traffic
Hi I have wordpress website
I am facing an issue with Google Analytics; it seems to be showing fake traffic. I checked on the search console as well, but it is showing me different traffic numbers, and I believe my site does not have as much traffic as Google Analytics is reporting. I have correctly embedded the Google Analytics code on the website, but I still don't know what the issue is. I really need help with this issue because it is very frustrating to not see accurate data. also according to Analytics, 90% of this traffic is coming from organic search, whereas the Google Search Console report is showing significantly lower traffic numbers.
Using two codes in header.php file

Do we need to use both codes, or can we use just one of them?
I saw that both these codes are included on my site, Could this code be the reason?
I tried to debug the website, but I didn't found anything wrong in website, except these two codes.

Please never mention your site on SO. This may be misinterpreted as link spam.
You only need GTM. Lines 141-147. The rest of the selected stuff can go. That's old/obsolete tracking.
In GTM, using its UI, you need to create rules to track things.
After the rules for tracking are implemented, you can test them in GTM preview. After tested, you need to publish them in GTM. That moves the changes to GTM's production and they start working on the site.
On the site, you open your network tab, filter requests by collect and inspect, making sure everything is tracked properly.
